# Google Maps Not Showing Marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

For some reason I can not get the marker to show on Google Maps - the map itself loads fine - it's just the marker I'm missing. I've tried moving all the code around in case it's a scope issue and what not but no luck so far.

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {

        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById('Latitude').value, document.getElementById('Longitude').value);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: myLatLng, visible: true });

        function init_map() {

            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 14,
                center: myLatLng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap_canvas"), myOptions);
            marker.setMap(map);

            $(window).resize(function () {
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
            });

            $('#accordion > .panel').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () { infowindow.open(map, marker); });
                var heading = $(this).find('.panel-heading');
                heading.addClass("active-panel");
            });

            $('#accordion > .panel').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function (e) {
                var heading = $(this).find('.panel-heading');
                heading.removeClass("active-panel");
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () { infowindow.open(map, marker); });

            })
        }


        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);


    });
```

Comment: Please create a fiddle, marker code looks correct - guessing the lat long part is not working.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w8ekcjj8/

Comment: your fiddle HTML doesn't contain any `Latitude` or `Longitude` elements

Comment: He meant a fiddle that recreates the problem. You're not including jquery and you're not including gmap's api. The people are not going to help you if you don't help them by showing the problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w8ekcjj8/ - it's all in there now - but it wont run at all - even if I include the API

Comment: Even if I chuck the whole page in both the accordion and the map dont work - but they do on my machine

Comment: Your fiddle still isn't including jquery, google maps, your own HTML that you'll need...

Comment: Yeah I put it all in just but it won't fire the accordion or the map so I figured that was no point passing something pointless over

Comment: it's not pointless, put it all in

Comment: ... although you could strip out all the accordion stuff, that's completely irrelevant to your problem. Create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help us diagnose the problem

Comment: Here's the new one stripped out - https://jsfiddle.net/r48xpray/

Comment: syntax error, the closing `});` is wrong. Run it all through http://www.jslint.com/ before proceeding

Comment: Fixed it - still no luck :(

Comment: Where's `infowindow` being created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Update Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w8ekcjj8/4/)

```
$(function () {
        init_map();
    });

function init_map() {

  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(document.getElementById('Latitude').value),
  parseFloat(document.getElementById('Longitude').value)); 

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: myLatLng, visible: true });

        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: myLatLng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap_canvas"), myOptions);
        marker.setMap(map); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to convert the strings that `document.getElementById('...').value` is returning, into floating point numbers that Google Maps will expect:

```
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(
    parseFloat(document.getElementById('Latitude').value), 
    parseFloat(document.getElementById('Longitude').value)
);
```

It's not the problem, but you shouldn't define your event listeners inside another event listener, like you're doing here:

```
$('#accordion > .panel').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    ...
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () { infowindow.open(map, marker); });
});
```

Just do it when you create the marker.

Comment: Just added than in and there's no change